# Default filter for admin sales order grid Magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, order-grid

If there is no active filter for sales order grid, I need to add a default filter in sales order grid in admin that will show only current date orders if no other filter are applied.
I need to do it with the code and no manual process for all admin users.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make use of the `Purchase Date` filter in the Sales Order grid.

e.g.
[image]

Comment: I want to make it with the code and not manual process.